# Pattern match guard with DateTime.TryParseExact?

Tags: f#, guard-clause

How to guard with `DateTime.TryParseExact` (and get the parsed value if possible)? The following code doesn't work.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let argList = args |> List.ofSeq
    match argList with
    | "aaa" :: [] -> aaa.main "aaa"
    | "bbb" :: [] -> bbb.main "bbb"
    | "ccc" :: yyyymm :: [] when DateTime.TryParseExact
              (yyyymm, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)-> 
        ccc.main "ccc" yyyymm
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `mutable`:

```
let mutable dt = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
match argList with
| "ccc" :: yyyymm :: [] when 
    DateTime.TryParseExact(yyyymm, 
                           "yyyyMM", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, 
                           &dt) -> ...
```

But an active pattern makes the match much clearer:

```
let (|DateTimeExact|_|) (format: string) s =
    match DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None) with
    | true, d -> Some d
    | _ -> None

match argList with
| "ccc" :: DateTimeExact "yyyyMM" yyyymm :: [] -> ...
```

Comment: Great. How to get the original string value of second item of the list (`yyyymm`) when using the active pattern? The type of `yyyymm` is `DateTime`. _Edit:_ I can update the `DateTimeExact` to return `Some s` to get the original string value. Curious what's the best way to get both the pre- and post- parsing values?

Comment: You could change the active pattern to return both: `Some(s, d)`